# Google Play Fused Location and GPS

Tags: android, gps, google-play-services, android-fusedlocation

I need clarification on `Google Play Fused Location`. 
I ask a high priority `(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)` but on my `Android (4.4.4)` I set the localization mode to `Saving Battery`: in this case `Google Play` don't use anyway the `GPS`, it's correct?

It think this because I try t use `Google Play Fused Location`, but if the `GPS` is off he use only the other methods for retrieve coords, and the obtained position is inaccurate (and I can't see the `GPS` icon on the status bar).

So, where is the advantage to use `Fused Location`? To retrieve an High accuracy position I need to set on the `GPS` anyway?

I really don't understand, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advantage of the Fused Location API is that it combines and manages all the different types of location providers into one easy to use api where as if you wanted to use the built in LocationManager you have to manage them all yourself

Comment: Ok, I undestand, BUT you confirm that if I set "Saving Battery" on the phone, Fused Location API don't turn on AUTOMATICALLY the GPS to get the position, even if I request LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY?

I absolutely need the most accurate position, 'cause my app is a sort of navigator.

Comment: correct if you turn off the GPS it will not look for the GPS

Comment: So, If I use the Fused, but I want to advice the user that is not using the most accurate GPS (and invite him to turn on the antenna) there's a way? I know how to make this with the "classic way" (onProviderDisabled…)

Comment: If you want to know if a specific provider is enabled or not you would do it the same way you always would by checking the provider